# systemd 212 returning stderr wrongly?

Tags: systemd

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

returns

```
 "Failed to wait for response: Success"
```

Checking my journal shows that the restart did happen.  But because this message is returned as a stderr, my ansible script shows me a "failure".  (Even though the restart did not fail.  I manually checked that my postgresql service is running as well).

This is obviously a bug?

Comment: Currently 215 is out. Report it if it still exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each job issued with systemctl has a timeout and your postgres service takes longer then expected. You can increase the timeout with the `TimeoutStopSec` or `TimeoutStartSec` options.
If it is not mandatory for your ansible playbook to wait for the result, you could also use the `--no-block` parameter for systemctl, which doesn't wait for job completion.

Comment: good tip regarding `--no-block`. Thanks.